# Should I close streams returned by Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream?

Tags: c#, stream

I had thought that it was good practice, when accessing embedded assembly resources using the `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` method, to close the returned `Stream` after finishing with it.  However, I just spotted something in the following article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950960.aspx

```
// Get the stream that holds the resource
// NOTE1: Make sure not to close this stream!
// NOTE2: Also be very careful to match the case
//        on the resource name itself
Stream stream =
  assem.GetManifestResourceStream("Azul.jpg");

// Load the bitmap from the stream
this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(stream);
```

The comment here says that the stream should *not* be closed, though the article makes no mention of why.  Searches on Google have provided nothing conclusive; some people seem to close this stream, others don't and say the garbage collector will deal with it.

Should I close streams returned by `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`?  Is there a particular reason I shouldn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That comment doesn't want you to close it because it goes on to create a `Bitmap` object from it.
Generally, you should close the streams once you're done using them or your application will be subject to memory leaks.

Comment: It does go on to create a bitmap from it, but why does it still not close it *after* creating the bitmap?

Comment: The example is using the Bitmap as a background image of a Windows Form, so the Bitmap (and the underlying stream) will be needed for the entire duration of the Form's life.  Unfortunately, it's not a very good example of showing how to properly manage IDisposable objects.